# How do you drop items?

Tags: starbound

I have a bunch of stuff in my inventory that I'll never want again. I have found that I can put items into the item bar thing, then select that as my active item, and press `Q` to throw it on the ground.

This is like 400% more effort than it should be to drop items onto the ground. Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to drop items; you can put them in the hotbar and press `q`, or you can also open your inventory, click on them, and then press `q`; because the item you just grabbed is now in your character's hands, it'll be dropped.

But, as of the [latest patch](http://playstarbound.com/changelog-for-v-furious-koala/), the developers claim to have made the following change:

> All player drops are persistent now.  So if you accidentally throw your diamond drill down a mineshaft, you don’t have to suicide trying to get it back before it disappears.

So, dropping items with `q` won't actually get rid of them; they'll sit around for eternity, just waiting for you. There's a far better way. On the inventory screen, there's a slot with a big "SEND TO TRASH" label on it; put items into that slot, and after a moment, they're gone. Forever. No longer cluttering anything up.

[image: Trash Slot]

Comment: I was mostly trying to figure out how to toss items to my coop partner easily, but my inventory is starting to get cluttered and the "send to trash" thing is going to be useful imminently.

Comment: @StrixVaria Ah. The question was worded in terms of getting rid of things permanently, and I figured a lot of people probably missed that dropping doesn't even work for that any more, as it was buried in the patch notes a bit.

Comment: This answered both questions I had, honestly, but I didn't want to ask two questions in one question, so it all worked out :)

Answer (score 1):

Can't try it out right now (game needs an update don't use my laptop that often), will edit the answer in a bit.

I am pretty sure that you can drag an item from the inventory (which activates it) and then drop it pressing `Q`.